# Setting the privileges of a new slide created using Google App Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, sharing

I created a new slide using a Google App script using

```
var targetDocument = SlidesApp.create("New Doc");
  var targetDocumentUrl = targetDocument.getUrl();
```

After making some modifications to the targetDocument (all of which work), I want to email the targetDocumentUrl to a particular person using the script

```
function sendEmail(recipient,subject,fileUrl){
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(getIdFromUrl(fileUrl));
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, 'Here is the file' + fileUrl + ' body of message', {
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],name: 'Auto Emailer'
 });  
}
```

While the email happens properly, the Url is not a public url. How do I ensure that the url is accessible by any recipient?
Did not find any attribute of the access privileges on google app script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

To create a public-shareable link of a particular file you can do the following:

```
function createSlide() {
  
  const name = "New Doc" 
  const targetDocument = SlidesApp.create(name);
  const targetDocumentUrl = targetDocument.getUrl();
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(targetDocument.getId());

//file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);  
  
}
```

If you are from a **G Suite** account use:

```
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

otherwise you should be able to use:

```
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

### Requirements:

Don't forget to activate Drive API: **Resouces** => **Advanced Google services**: enable **Drive API**:

[image: Enable Drive API]

### References:

[Enum Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access)